# Loop through all child elements in a array with handlebars

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, handlebars.js

I want to loop through all **products** in below array using **handlebars**, I am not used handlebars before. Issue is **products** can use in any level, can't predict in which level we can have **products** If this can be done using native javascript please mentioned that solution too. Could someone help me with this ?? :).....

```
var data = [
    {
        category: "Deserts",
        products: [
            {
                name: "AAAA",
                price: "aaaa"
            },
            {
                name: "BBBB",
                price: "bbbb"
            }
      ]
  },
  {
      category: "Unit Documents",
      children : [
          {
               children : [
                   {
                       products: [
                           {
                               name: "CCCC",
                               price: "cccc"
                           }
                       ]
                   }
              ],
              products: [
                  {
                      name: "DDDD",
                      price: "dddd"
                  },
                  {
                      name: "EEEE",
                      price: "eeee"
                  },
                  {
                      name: "FFFF",
                      price: "ffff"
                  }
             ]
         },
         {
             products: [
                 {
                      name: "GGGG",
                      price: "gggg"
                 },
                 {
                      name: "HHHH",
                      price: "hhhh"
                 }
             ]
        }
    ],
    products: [
       {
            name: "IIII",
            price: "iiii"
       }
   ]
   },
   {
        Category: "Minutes"
   }
];
```

Comment: Have you even tried looking up the answer your self? Because it says how to do it right in the [handlebars docs](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html).

Comment: @Olian04 Careful now. I once got accused of being rude because I basically expected posters to not be rude by posting questions that they could easily have answered themselves had they bothered to ... I don't know ... read anything about what they were trying to do. Apparently that sort of rudeness is ok here but pointing it out in anyway that doesn't completely nut cup the poster is not.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a solution using handlebar and an inline partial. I hope this will help.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context =[
    {
        category: "Deserts",
        products: [
            {
                name: "AAAA",
                price: "aaaa"
            },
            {
                name: "BBBB",
                price: "bbbb"
            }
      ]
  },
  {
      category: "Unit Documents",
      children : [
          {
               children : [
                   {
                       products: [
                           {
                               name: "CCCC",
                               price: "cccc"
                           }
                       ]
                   }
              ],
              products: [
                  {
                      name: "DDDD",
                      price: "dddd"
                  },
                  {
                      name: "EEEE",
                      price: "eeee"
                  },
                  {
                      name: "FFFF",
                      price: "ffff"
                  }
             ]
         },
         {
             products: [
                 {
                      name: "GGGG",
                      price: "gggg"
                 },
                 {
                      name: "HHHH",
                      price: "hhhh"
                 }
             ]
        }
    ],
    products: [
       {
            name: "IIII",
            price: "iiii"
       }
   ]
   },
   {
        Category: "Minutes"
   }
];

 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#*inline "myPartialLoopOverProducts"}}
{{#each this}}
{{#each products}}
<li>{{name}} : {{price}}</li>
{{/each}}
{{>myPartialLoopOverProducts this}}
{{/each}}
{{/inline}}

Products:
<ul>
{{>myPartialLoopOverProducts this}}
</ul>
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```